# How to make a Firebase messaging function asynchronous

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase messaging function, but the return function seems to execute before the rest of the functions. Here is the code (sorry its long):

```
exports.newMessageNotification = functions.firestore
  .document(`messages/{messageId}`) // wildcard for the msg id
  .onCreate(async (change, context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const messageId: string = context.params.messageId;
    const messageRef = db.collection('messages').doc(messageId);
    const tokens = [];

    // get the message
    const message: Message = await messageRef
      .get()
      .then(q => q.data() as Message);

    const recipients: any = await message.recipients;

    const user: User = await db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(message.senderId)
      .get()
      .then(q => {
        return q.data() as User;
      });

    // Notification content
    const payload = await {
      notification: {
        title: `${user.name}`,
        body: `${message.message}`,
      },
    };

    console.log(payload);

    // loop though each recipient, get their devices and push to tokens
    Object.keys(recipients).forEach(async recipient => {
      const devicesRef = db
        .collection('devices')
        .where('userId', '==', recipient);
      const devices = await devicesRef.get();

      devices.forEach(res => {
        const token: string = res.data().token;
        console.log(token);
        tokens.push(token);
      });
    });

    console.log(tokens); // logs empty
    return await sendToCloud(tokens, payload);
  });
```

I think the issue is that the forEach is not asynchronous so the final line of code is executing before waiting for forEach to finish?

Comment: Bottom line is that you should collect all the promises into an array, then use Promise.all to wait for the entire batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh. I had this problem somewhere recently. You are correct, at least in my experience: `forEach` does not seem to obey the `async` directive. I had to use the `for ... in ...` syntax to:

1. Get it to obey `async` (from the parent scope)
2. Process sequentially, as order was important to me at the time

In your case, it would probably look like `for (const recipient in recipients) { ... }`

---

Apparently, this is caused by `forEach` calling the callback on each item without awaiting a response. Even if the callback is asynchronous, `forEach` doesn't know to `await` its response on each loop.

Source: https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

---

A solution from [the comments](https://medium.com/@pyapar/another-approach-using-map-instead-of-foreach-82a85f536c9c) on the blog linked above:

```
await Promise.all(
  Object.keys(recipients).map(async recipient => {
    const devicesRef = db
      .collection('devices')
      .where('userId', '==', recipient);
    const devices = await devicesRef.get();

    devices.forEach(res => {
      const token: string = res.data().token;
      console.log(token);
      tokens.push(token);
    });
  });
)
```

Note the `forEach` has been replaced by a `map`, and it's within `Promise.all(...)`.

Comment: forEach is not really "naive".  This is just how lambda functions all work in JS when doing functional programming.

Comment: Thank you Brian - that now works perfectly. I just needed to remove one the last semi colon as TS was complaining